# How to upload a file from webpage to Google Cloud Storage using Ajax, Java, Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to upload a file along with some other information but at the server side i am getting an error as
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.

My Requirement is to save the uploaded file to Google Cloud Storage using GCS Client Library. Please Help.

Here is my code:
HTML Form

```
<form id="createWorkerForm">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="photoCopy" name="photoCopy" placeholder="Photo Copy">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="createWorker">
</form>
```

Jquery Ajax

```
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: url+"/uploadPic",
    type: "POST",
    enctype:"multipart/form-data",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function(response) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("unable to create the record");
    }
});
```

Dispatcher Servlet - Configuration to support Multipart File Upload

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Method in Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createWorker",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String createWorker(HttpServletRequest req){
    FileItemIterator iterator;
    FileItemStream item;
    InputStream stream = null;
    try{

        String firstName = req.getParameter("firstName"));
        ServletFileUpload upload =new ServletFileUpload();
        iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            item = iterator.next();
            stream = item.openStream();

            if (item.isFormField()) {
                log.warning("Got a form field: " + item.getFieldName());
            } else {
                log.warning("Got an uploaded file: " + item.getFieldName() +
                        ", name = " + item.getName());


            }
        }

        return "success";
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        ErrorUtil.printErrorLog(className, "showIndexPage", e);
        return "fail";
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
at org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream.thresholdReached(DeferredFileOutputStream.java:122)
at org.apache.commons.io.output.ThresholdingOutputStream.checkThreshold(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:221)
at org.apache.commons.io.output.ThresholdingOutputStream.write(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:128)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:107)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:156)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:139)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:892)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Please Help..!!!

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution.

```
<!-- this line will not work with google app engine -->
<bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

<!-- this will work with google app engine -->
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.gmr.web.multipart.GMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1048576" />
</bean>
```

refer: https://code.google.com/p/gmultipart/